# Linkedin Follow Button is not Displaying in Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7, mean-stack

Here is the code

```html
<script src="https://platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"> lang: en_US</script>
<script type="IN/FollowCompany" data-id="1337" data-counter="bottom"></script>
```

I have used this docs [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/follow-company-plugin)

I have implemented the code on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ugc1ge?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Is there anyway to solve this in Angular?

Comment: what is the id of your company page ?

Comment: here is the demo id 1337

Comment: demo link won't work, `https://www.linkedin.com/company/1337/admin/`. company id should be valid id.

Comment: It is working on simple Html file but not in angular

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"> lang: en_US</script>
<script type="IN/FollowCompany" data-id="1337" data-counter="bottom"></script>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Just try the above one code on jsbin

Comment: check my comment below. I have provided solution

Answer (score 0):

use this code.

```
<script src="https://platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="IN/FollowCompany" data-id="361557" data-counter="right"></script>
```

Issue was in in.js script url.
[Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-linkedin-follow)

attching screenshot also.
[image]
Let me know if you have any issue.

Comment: But this is not working on app.component.html https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sefgnt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Can you please review once

Comment: I have moved code to app.component.html, but it will show CORS issue, you need to enable CORS.

Comment: it is working for me even after moving to app.component.html

Comment: How you are enabling CORS through chrome extension or some any other way?

Comment: you can use this addon - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cors-unblock/lfhmikememgdcahcdlaciloancbhjino?hl=en

Comment: But extension is not convenient for the users might be they are not aware that much is there any other way?

Comment: You need to handle CORS on your server

Comment: After enabling the CORS still button is not displaying https://prnt.sc/sx4cq8

Comment: did you wait for it ? it takes time to display.

Comment: Yes, Waited for more than 2 mins.